# Miscellaneous Solids. How do I solve this problem?

Tags: integration, 3d, volume

Can anybody help me with this

> Find the volume in the first octant inside the cylinder $x^2/a^2 +y^2/b^2 =1$ under the plane $z=3x$. Use the given slice in the figure to compute the volume.
>
> [image: this is the figure to be used]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the figure, the volume is

$$\int_{y=0}^{b} \frac{xz}{2}dy$$
$$= \int_{y=0}^{b} \frac{3x^2}{2}dy$$
$$= \int_{y=0}^{b} \frac{3}{2}a^2(1 - \frac{y^2}{b^2})dy = a^2b$$

Answer (score -1):

Using ellipse coordenates for the double integral:

$$\int\int_D\left(\int_0^{3x}1\,dz\right)\,dx\,dy=\int\int_D3x\,dx\,dy=3\,a^2\,b\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1\,r^2\,\cos \theta\,dr\,d\theta=\boxed{a^2\,b}$$